# Adjust Label based on text size in Xamarin IOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, uilabel

Auto Adjust UILabel size based on text.

```
lbl_genericIndicators.Font = UIFont.FromName (KHELVETIC, KFontSize12);
float width = View.Frame.Size.Width-20;
SizeF size = ((NSString)lbl_genericIndicators.Text).StringSize(lbl_genericIndicators.Font,constrainedToSize:new SizeF(width,100),
lineBreakMode:UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
var labelFrame = lbl_genericIndicators.Frame;
labelFrame.Size = new SizeF(width,size.Height);
lbl_genericIndicators.Frame = new RectangleF (10, 128, size.Width,size.Height);
```

**Below is the sample text:**

> UITextView displays a region that can contain multiple lines of When a
>   user taps a text view, a keyboard appears; when a user taps Return in
>   the keyboard, the keyboard disappears and the text view can handle the
>   input in an application-specific way. You can specify attributes, such
>   as font, color, and alignment, that apply to all text in a text view.

[image]

The above text I am using for example.  It need to adjust automatically  for display the  content.

Answer (score 4):

**Resolved with below Code**

```
lbl_genericIndicators.Font = UIFont.FromName (KHELVETIC, KFontSize12);
lbl_genericIndicators.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
lbl_genericIndicators.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Justified;
float width = View.Frame.Size.Width-20;
SizeF size=((NSString)lbl_genericIndicators.Text).StringSize(lbl_genericIndicators.Font,constrainedToSize:new SizeF(width,100),lineBreakMode:UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
var labelFrame = lbl_genericIndicators.Frame;
labelFrame.Size = new SizeF(width,size.Height);
lbl_genericIndicators.Lines = int.Parse((lbl_genericIndicators.Text.Length / 40).ToString()) + 1;
lbl_genericIndicators.Frame = new RectangleF (10, 128, size.Width,size.Height);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code snippet that I use for resizing the label height according to its contents

```
void ChangeLabelHeigthWithText(UITextView label,float maxHeight = 100f) 
        {
            float width = label.Frame.Width; 
            SizeF size = ((NSString)label.Text).StringSize(label.Font,constrainedToSize:new SizeF(width,maxHeight),
                    lineBreakMode:UILineBreakMode.WordWrap);
            var labelFrame = label.Frame;
            labelFrame.Size = new SizeF(width,size.Height);
            label.Frame = labelFrame;
        }
```